# php namespace class not found - twig composer

Tags: php, class, namespaces, twig, composer-php

I searched and tried all the answers and have had no success.

I have a small MVC that was working just fine till I added namespaces. Errors everywhere. My current error I Think might be related to composer autoload. As my current error is with Twig. **Which I should note works perfectly fine when I remove all namespaces.**

My Last error was the same error as this but with View class. I resolved it by putting View.php in Viewer folder instead of either the Core or Controller folder

Error

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'app\Core\Viewer\Twig_Loader_Filesystem' not found in G:\site\app\Core\Viewer\View.php:40 Stack trace: #0 G:\site\app\Core\Controller\Controller.php(13): app\Core\Viewer\View->__construct('index.twig', Array) #1 G:\site\app\controllers\mycms.php(14): app\Core\Controller\Controller::view('index.twig', Array) #2 [internal function]: myCMS::index() #3 G:\site\app\Core\App.php(68): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4 G:\site\public\index.php(13): Core\App->__construct() #5 {main} thrown in G:\site\app\Core\Viewer\View.php on line 40
```

File Structure - Not full structure only effected files

```
| common.php - Includes all dependency's
| composer.json
| 
├────app
|    |     bootstrap.php - simply includes everything in app
|    |
|    ├───Core
|        |     App.php - uses namespace app\Core
|        |               Class name App
|        |
|        ├───Controller
|        |          Controller.php - uses namespace app\Core\Controller
|        |                           Class name Controller
|        ├───Viewer
|        |         Viewer.php - uses namespace app\Core\Viewer
|        |                      Class name View
|
├───public
|   |      index.php - includes common.php which includes everything else
|
├───vendor - typical composer structure
|   |    autoload.php
    ├───twig
```

composer.json - I feel this is where the problem is. I used "composer dumpautoload" already

```
{
    "require": {
        "twig/twig": "~1.0",
        other dependency's...
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "app\\Core\\": "app/Core"
        }
    }
}
```

Controller.php

```
namespace app\Core\Controller;

use app\Core\Viewer as View;

class Controller {

    public static function view($viewName, $data)
    {
        $view = new View($viewName, $data);

        ...
    }
}
```

View.php

```
namespace app\Core\Viewer;

class View
{
    ....
}
```

That should cover what I think the problem might be. Let me know if you want more posted and I will update my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that in your `View` class you are using the `Twig_Loader_Filesystem` right?

So you have to use it like `\Twig_Loader_Filesystem` notice the leading backslash.

Comment: That was it! namespacing has a lot to it. Lots to update. Thanks so much!

Comment: Namespaces always start relative from the one you are currently in, hence the error you've got `Class 'app\Core\Viewer\Twig_Loader_Filesystem' not found`. The autoloader was expecting the class being in the namespace `app/Core/Viewer`, which was incorrect